# How to auto attach any putty or kitty console to ConEmu

Tags: putty, conemu, kitty

Is it possible to auto attach any putty.exe or kitty.exe console windows to ConEmu?
If yes, then how can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean with "auto attach"?

Comment: well, at least, when you have your ConEmu open and then open, e.g. putty.exe console window, then it could auto attach to ConEmu as a new tab.

Comment: even better, if you do not have a ConEmu app running yet, and you launch putty, then it could open ConEmu and open putty in its tab

Comment: Why not to run putty in ConEmu? The way you want to run PuTTY matters.

Comment: yeah, It does, actually, that is why I asked. When you run, e.g. putty or kitty, you get a configuration window, where one can choose any saved connection, and then open it. If you do it from putty/kitty GUI, console is started outside ConEmu, but I would like to have it automatically opened as ConEmu tab.

Comment: But there is *no* putty/kitty GUI... It *is* GUI. So, how do you start putty/kitty??? Do you doubleclick shortcut on desktop, do you run Win+R "putty", do you... I can't imagine what do you do.

Comment: Everything is easy - I just run putty or kitty with single left mouse click, then a GUI window is opened, where one can select/configure connections. When I click "open" for a saved connection, then new console window is opened, but, sadly, outside of ConEmu. So the question was - IS IT POSSIBLE TO MAKE ConEmu grab/attach newly opened putty or kitty consoles to its tabs automatically. Thank you.

Comment: I have found the way, without creating shortcut for every task. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking to do the same thing and found this link

http://www.thecrumb.com/2013/03/04/configuring-conemu-and-putty/

I think it's basically what Maximus was saying but you will do this from inside ConEmu

Comment: yes, you are right, it is possible to do it one by one, but if you open connections with putty GUI, then connection console is outside ConEmu - that is the problem, I am trying to solve.

Comment: if you open PuTTY without any switches via ConEmu then the config window appears and the console itself gets sucked into a tab after you did the setup

Answer (score 3):

Guys I just found the way! Totally possible **without** create shortcut for every session to load.

I just found that CMDER has a default task named `{Putty}`. It just launches `Putty.exe` directly (so `putty.exe` should be in path, or you should specify the full path of `putty.exe`).

[image]

Create a shortcut of CMDer with arguments:

```
<full-path-to-cmder.exe> /task Putty
```

Open it, and the Putty prompt shows. Load your session as usual, and it now shows in Cmder instead of putty, voila!

[image]

I knew such a common requirement has a solution in CMDER. Perfect!

Except that you have no control over the tab title, but we cannot ask for more...

**EDIT**:

I just found that we can specify the window title in Putty when we use Cmder, so now my solution becomes more than perfect.

In putty, we can set a window title in "Window" - "Behaviour", and in Cmder, we set the tab to use putty window title in "Main" - "Tab bar" - "Tab templates" - "Console" (`%s` represents the title, as shown in the tips above "Console".)

Another two screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative simply use SSH

```
ssh root@somehost
```

For example add the tools packaged with Git to your path

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
```

Or powershell path

```
# %UserProfile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
# Add linux tools from git
$env:Path += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"
```

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx

... And if going down that tangent consider only asking for your key passphrase once and Powershell with Posh git

- http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx/
- http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx/

Comment: assuming you're using PuTTY for SSH...

Comment: No git bash is built with MinGW, no PuTTY here

Answer (score 1):

Single click? I think you are meaning "shortcut click".

So, change your shortcut properties.

**Example 1**

```
ConEmuC.exe /ATTACH /ROOT PuTTY.exe <your PuTTY switches>
```

**Example 2**

```
ConEmu.exe /single /cmd PuTTY.exe <your PuTTY switches>
```

Thought, you need to use full paths to executables.

Comment: this is a good comment, but the problem is, that for every connection I have in putty/kitty I need to make a shortcut, that is a lot of work, that surely can be done, but not very elegant))

Comment: What I need is when ANY putty session is opened it automatically attached to ConEmu as a tab.

Comment: You still have NOT said, how exactly you are running your PuTTY instance!

Comment: Actually he did. He simply wants to start it the normal way so he gets the config popup and can choose a saved session and when it actually starts the session it should be attached.

Comment: so, yeah, Blizz is right, I am starting a putty/kitty session just a normal way like this: http://screencast.com/t/cpLCTdV8bU
But the window is not attached automatically to ConEmu, hope it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: So, after clicking an "Open" button in Kitty configuration, a new console windows is opened like this: http://screencast.com/t/UIPhBAjIf9Z

Thank you for trying to solve this mystery, Maximus!)

Comment: Kitty is not a console application. It has its own GUI. And ConEmu must not hook those windows. Workaround is changing path to ConEmu.exe.

Answer (score 0):

AntonioCS has the correct link.

I was struggling with this too. The key is not to put the full path for putty in the conemu task command. Instead, make sure the path to putty is in your Windows, User profile environment variable, and then just call out putty by itself:

```
Putty.exe -new_console -load "(name of session)"
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding to KCD's answer, yet another option is using SSH under Cmder for Windows[http://cmder.net/], as shown in this article:

- http://richb-hanover.com/cmder-for-windows-alternative-to-putty/

One needs only to type:

> ssh user@hostname

A great advantage pointed in the article is that "*Cmder is easy on the eyes, with attractive fonts, default Monokai color scheme, and resizable windows*".

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The question is about ConEmu **not** Cmder.

Comment: That's right, @DavidPostill. I just thought it was worth suggesting.

Comment: `cmder` uses `conemu` underneath